# Spark Sql 1.6 Key Not Found when there is a case mismatch for field names in DataFrame and in Hive Table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider there's a hive table that is partitioned

```
create table hivetbl(a int,b int) partitioned by(c int);
```

Now if we try to insert into the table through Spark DataFrame

```
Seq((1, 2, 3)).toDF("A", "B","C").write.partitionBy("C").insertInto("hivetbl");
```

It throws

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: c
```

Whereas, if I change the structure of the 
dataFrame to

```
Seq((1, 2, 3)).toDF("a", "b", "c").write.partitionBy("c").insertInto("hivetbl");
```

*Data gets loaded into the table.*

Shouldn't spark  handle this case mismatch that's happening between the DataFrame and hive table as hive is not case sensitive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is lots of discussions about **case sensitivity**, but since spark 1.5 (if I'm not mistaken) this is configurable.

You can change the Spark SQL configuration for case sensitivity using:

```
sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=false")
```

And the reason why it should be like is that `SQLContext` deals with many types of data sources, and in some where case sensitivity sounds logical in other cases, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Error is happening inside Spark. 
Spark is case-sensitive, so in his own interpreter you have to take care of that, even if it is irrelevant to other applications in your hadoop system.